# Mostrar un ImageView y TextView Funcionando

Tags: android, loops, android-imageview, textview

Mostrar un `ImageView` durante 1s y pasado el tiempo la imagen se borre y luego muestre un `TextView` durante 1s, y asi sucesivamente hasta recorrer toda la `List`. forma de hacerlo:

Codigo:

De esta forma quedo funcionando:

Gracias a el aporte de :

> Andrespengineer

Declaraciones...

```
private int currentPosition = 0;
public ArrayList<Bitmap> ItemsBitmap;
public Bitmap bitmap;

public Bits items;
```

Inicializo:

```
ItemsBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++){
        Bits item = L.get(i);
        ItemsBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));

    }
    for (int x = 0; x < L.size(); x++){
        Bits item = L.get(x);
        nameBit.setText(item.getbText());
    }
    showImages();
```

Metodo:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showImages() {
    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        boolean continuar = true; // Si quieres que se detenga, vuelve continuar false en algun momento
        int number = 0;
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if(number % 2 != 0) {
                if(number == 101)
                    number = -1; // esto hace que la bandera no crezca mucho
                imageBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nameBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
                imageBit.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                items = L.get(currentPosition);
                nameBit.setText(items.getbText());
                currentPosition++;
                if (ItemsBitmap.size() == currentPosition) {
                    currentPosition = 0; // Esto hace que se vuelva a repetir la lista de Bitmaps
                }
                imageBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (L.size() == currentPosition){
                    currentPosition = 0;
                }
                nameBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            number++;
        }
        public void onFinish() {

            if (continuar) {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Ya quedo resuelt....

Comment: Por lo que veo, estás preguntando dos veces lo mismo. Esto intentemos evitarlo por favor. Además, como referencia a futuros lectores, no estaría mal que comentes cuál de las respuestas solucionó tu problema, cuestión de ordenar un poco el lío que se generó acá

Comment: Ya edite el contenido, publicando la solucion a lo que se requeria y dando gracias a la persona que dio aporte a la solucion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero intenta crear una lista de Bitmaps llamada `ItemsBitmap`, declarar `currentPosition` global y crear una variable para almacenar el `bitmap` global también:

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> ItemsBitmap;
public Bitmap bitmap;
public currentPosition = 0;
```

Ahora inicializa la lista con los bitmaps antes de llamar al método showImages:

```
ItemsBitmap = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++){
   Bits item = L.get(i);
   ItemsBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
}
showImages();
```

Aqui el método:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showImages() {
        bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
        imageBit.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            boolean continuar = true; // Si quieres que se detenga, vuelve continuar false en algun momento
            int number = 0;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(number % 2 != 0) {
                    if(number == 101)
                      number = 0; // esto hace que la bandera no crezca mucho
                    imageBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    currentPosition++;
                    if (ItemsBitmap.size() == currentPosition) {
                        currentPosition = 0; // Esto hace que se vuelva a repetir la lista de Bitmaps
                    }
                    imageBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                number++;
            }
            public void onFinish() {

                if (continuar) {
                    this.start();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Lo probé y me funciona perfecto, dejame saber si te funciona.

Comment: Si me funciono ya quedo, con las modificaciones que le hice. Gracias!!